# What is a multi channel supervised classifier?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-learning, supervised-learning

I came across a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.10077) that describes its model architecture in the following way.

> Our TRIL network is a **two-channel network** jointly trained to predict the expert’s action given state and the system’s next state transition given state and expert action. The training procedure of TRIL is similar to that of a multi- channel supervised classifier with regularization. Let $\theta_{π_0}$ be the parameters of TRIL and $L_{ce}$ be the cross entropy loss for predicting expert’s action and $L_{mse}$ be the mean squared error loss on predicting next state given current state and the expert’s action

The loss function is given in the following manner
$$L(\theta_{\pi_0}) = L_{ce}(a, \pi_0(s)) + \lambda L_{mse}(T_{\pi_0}(s,a),s')$$

> TRIL is a dual- channel network that **shares certain hidden layers** and **jointly predicts** expert action(a) and state transitions(s’)

I am not sure what a dual channel network means and what does it mean when it is able to jointly predict two outputs ? It seems something similar to a multi-task learning since there is shared hidden layers and different "task" prediction but i am not too sure of that either.